# Disable debug console window when debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When debug in android studio, I know press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to open "run" window, and press
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to open "Debug" window, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> to open "logcat" window.
 Then what is Debug console window, as shown below, I don't think it's useful and want to disable it.

[image]

Comment: or any way to restore default layout?

Comment: I wonder whether there is a way to disable it by default, rather than click 'Hide' everytime.

Answer (score 0):

So simple,just right Click tab name, and select "Hide"

Comment: So simple, that's why you asked it?

Comment: @Khemraj sorry, I spent almost a hour to find this, "simple" is the result not the process

Comment: Don't sorry at all, It will help someone needed.